# select Data between two date range mysql return wrong values

Tags: mysql, query, date

I want to select data between **9/Nov/2018** and **11/Nov/2018**, but the result seems wrong - it returned data outside the two ranges. Using the below query...

```
select * 
from radacct 
where DATE_FORMAT(radacct.AcctStartTime,'%d %M %Y') 
    between STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%d %M %Y') 
        AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-11','%d %M %Y');
```

...I got back data like this...

```
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 12463 |  2018-10-11 16:22:21  |  2018-10-11 17:23:07  |        2018-10-11 16:22:21  |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 12523 |  2018-10-11 17:16:01  |  2018-10-11 17:16:10  |       2018-10-11 17:16:01   |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

...as you see, the date is 2018-10-11. How did this happen?

Comment: Explain, why you convert field value to string whereas literals to date? in WHERE clause...

Answer (score 2):

Tip:  Test uses of functions:

Your first use of str_to_date:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%d %M %Y');  SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%d %M %Y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                        |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-9' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Aha -- It's year-month-day, not day-month-year:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y %M %d');  SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y %M %d') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                        |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-9' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Wait, `m`, not `M`:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y %m %d');  SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y %m %d') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                        |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2018-11-9' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Oh, yeah, the dashes need to be specified:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y-%m-%d');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-9','%Y-%m-%d') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2018-11-09                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, anyway, you can simply use the string  `'2018-11-9'`, no conversion needed!

Or, fix the string a different way (now needing slashes, but M and order are correct:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9/Nov/2018','%d/%M/%Y');
+--------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('9/Nov/2018','%d/%M/%Y') |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2018-11-09                           |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```